# Is there a similar command like .call for .NET?

Tags: .net, windbg

With `.call` it seems possible to call native functions (never actually tried it). Is there a similar command for calling .NET functions to [mimic this result](http://dailydotnettips.com/2014/01/01/automatically-calling-a-method-when-a-breakpoint-is-hit/)?

I'm looking for WinDbg solutions only. I know that Visual Studio has the Immediate window and other tools like [Hawkeye](http://hawkeye.codeplex.com/) can call event handlers and maybe [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) can call methods as well.

Comment: May I know why this is voted to be closed?

Comment: Probably because those who voted did not understand the question =) It's usually a good idea/etiquette for close-voters to try and get the OP to improve the question they regard as deserving to be closed before actually voting to close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer is no.

The problem is that you can't run managed code on any arbitrary thread. And even if you are on a good thread, then it can easily cause issues with garbage collection, finalizers, etc.

In the past we've tried creating a native entry point which will then call out to the managed code. It was messy and didn't work a good chunk of the time that it was needed.

Edit:
`.call` works by pushing a bunch of stuff onto the stack, jumping to the entry point, and then continues execution (all on the currently selected thread). Unfortunately WinDbg itself doesn't know anything about managed code, how it interacts with the system, or how it can safely be invoked. The Visual Studio debugger (which is a *very* different debugging engine) knows about managed code and how to cleanly execute a method.

Comment: As you worked 13 years for Microsoft I think I can immediately accept this answer and no longer think about it. But how can Visual Studio manage it then?